Anychart treemap adjusted font size
In anychart treemap, I want the font size to change dynamically according to the value when using adjusted font size function.
In short, when I use the set font size, the font size is too big. I want the fonts to be smaller by, say, 20%
thank u.
when I use the set font size, the font size is too big. I want the fonts to be smaller by, say, 20%

While you can't manipulate the font size used by labels of the treemap chart after you use the adjustFontSize() method, you can achieve similar behaviour with a custom formatting function, as shown in the sample below.


anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

  // get data
  var data = getData();

  // create a chart and set the data
  var chart = anychart.treeMap(data, "as-tree");

  // get the biggest value in your data
  var maxValue = data[0].children.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=>{
    return Math.max(accumulator, currentValue.value)
  }, data[0].children[0].value);

  // set min and max font size for your chart labels
  var minFontSize = 7;
  var maxFontSize = 30;

  // claculate the multiplayer for the font size 
  var multiplayer = (maxFontSize - minFontSize) / maxValue;

  // setup formatter for lebels
  var labels = chart.labels();
  labels.format(function(){

    // calculate the resulting font size based on min max and multiplayer
    var resultingFontSize = minFontSize + this.value * multiplayer;

    // setup label and its content
    var label = labels.getLabel(this.index);
    label.fontSize(resultingFontSize);
    return this.name + '\n' + this.value
  });

  // set the container id
  chart.container("container");

  // initiate drawing the chart
  chart.draw();
});

// create data
function getData(){
  return [
    {name:   "European Union", children: [
      {name: "Belgium",        value: 11443830, capital: "Brussels" },
      {name: "France",         value: 64938716, capital: "Paris"    },
      {name: "Germany",        value: 80636124, capital: "Berlin"   },
      {name: "Greece",         value: 10892931, capital: "Athens"   },
      {name: "Italy",          value: 59797978, capital: "Rome"     },
      {name: "Netherlands",    value: 17032845, capital: "Amsterdam"},
      {name: "Poland",         value: 38563573, capital: "Warsaw"   },
      {name: "Romania",        value: 19237513, capital: "Bucharest"}, 
      {name: "Spain",          value: 46070146, capital: "Madrid"   },
      {name: "United Kingdom", value: 65511098, capital: "London"   }  
    ]} 
  ];
}
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.1/js/anychart-base.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.1/js/anychart-treemap.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.12.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js?hcode=a0c21fc77e1449cc86299c5faa067dc4"></script>
<div id="container"></div>




How to word-wrap the lable? If the lable is big it gets cut off and doesn't go to next line?
